# Hide the "free trial" text from Woocommerce Subscriptions price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to remove the "with a XX day free trial" from my product, cart and checkout pages. I need to have the feature still work without having to express it in the product details.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the filter hook [`'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string'`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/filter-reference/) for this hooked function, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'subscriptions_custom_price_string', 20, 3 );
function subscriptions_custom_price_string( $price_string, $product, $args ) {
    // Get the trial length to check if it's enabled
    $trial_length = $product->get_meta('_subscription_trial_length');
    if( $trial_length > 0 )
        $price_string = $args['price'];

    return $price_string;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Tested and works.