# Remove WooCommerce subscription interval from cart and checkout pages

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, checkout, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to remove the `/ month` or `/ year` on the cart and checkout page for Woocommerce Subscriptions.

So Instead of `$99 / year` I only want to show `$99`

Hoping someone can point me i. the right direction.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the following, that will clean everything except the recurring price and totals:

```
// Items pricing
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'filter_wc_subscriptions_product_price_string', 10, 3 );
function filter_wc_subscriptions_product_price_string( $price_string, $product, $args ) {
    if ( is_cart() || ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) {
        return $args['price'];
    }
    return $price_string;
}

// Total lines
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscription_price_string', 'filter_wc_subscription_price_string', 10, 2 );
function filter_wc_subscription_price_string( $subscription_string, $subscription_details ) {
    if ( is_cart() || ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) {
        $recurring_amount = $subscription_details['recurring_amount'];
        
        if( is_numeric( $recurring_amount ) ) {
            return strip_tags( wc_price($recurring_amount) ); // For shipping methods
        }
        else {
            return $recurring_amount;
        }
    }
    return $subscription_string;
}
```

Based on:

- [WooCommerce Subscriptions Filter Reference documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/filter-reference/)
- [Hide the "free trial" text from Woocommerce Subscriptions price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936530/hide-the-free-trial-text-from-woocommerce-subscriptions-price/48938813#48938813)

Comment: Wow, this is perfect. You are a genius! Thank you so much.

Comment: Can this function be extended to also remove the "/ month" from all emails ( new order, renewal ) and also the confirmation page? Thank you

Comment: @user1664798 The best thing is to try… If it doesn't work, ask a new question clear and detailed, with a link to this thread.