# Remove WooCommerce subscription duration from cart and checkout pages

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, checkout, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to remove the `duration` on the cart and checkout page for Woocommerce Subscriptions.

So instead of `$99 / month for 12 months` only `$99 / month` (${price} / {period})

The solution on the following topic removes the whole string after the price. Maybe it helps to find a solution for my case.
([Remove WooCommerce subscription interval from cart and checkout pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62775318/remove-woocommerce-subscription-interval-from-cart-and-checkout-pages#new-answer))

Helpful resource: [WooCommerce Subscriptions Filter Reference documentation](https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/filter-reference/)

I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('wcs_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'modify_wcs_cart_totals_order_total_html', 100, 2);

function modify_wcs_cart_totals_order_total_html($order_total_html, $cart) {
    $recurring_total_string = explode('für', $order_total_html);
    $recurring_first_string = explode('Erste', $order_total_html);
    return $recurring_total_string[0]. '<div class="first-payment-date"><small>Erste'.$recurring_first_string[1].' </small></div>';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesnt work. It still shows the duration

Comment: @nvoy This will remove the specified string from the cart total in cart and checkout pages.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/PrrBTgKB/Screenshot-2022-02-18-120150.png

Here is the screenshot with the filter in functions.php applied

Comment: This worked just fine (https://i.postimg.cc/g04nxwfY/Screenshot-2022-02-18-124147.png). 

Is it possible to keep the "first payment on:" under the reccuring total (see first screenshot)? Thank you!

Comment: In the staging environment it works like a charm. But the other strings still show it. Please see this screenshot to understand what it should look like:  https://i.postimg.cc/zG8GhCp6/Screenshot-2022-02-18-151723.png

Thank you very much!